# Underrated microswitch in consumer product odd?

Tags: switches, ac

I'm currently looking at modifying a coffee grinder for automation purposes and whilst tearing it down and inspecting the components I noticed the model of micro switch used for the start/stop button and 2 others physical sensors are only rated for 3A / 125VAC according to the manufacturer specs and I live in the UK so it's receiving 240VAC. (Doesn't look like there's any voltage conversion circuitry).

Is this odd, or because it's a low current load it's not an issue and standard practice?

---

Photos of PCB (originals [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kdDo.jpg)):

[image: PCB top view]

[image: PCB bottom view]

Comment: Find the part number and check the datasheet for any indication it can be used at 240V. Does the product have the safety approval markings that it is suitable for use in UK/EU?

Comment: I have checked the datasheet and there's no indication it can be used at 240V. The product does have appropriate safety markings (CE) for UK/EU use.

Comment: What would happen if the switch failed? If the answer is "nothing dangerous" then it might not be included in the safety assessment. Hard to see how that would be true for a start/stop switch though.  Alternatively, where did it come from? Fraudulent CE marks are unfortunately pretty common.

Comment: Possibly there is but I just don't know what to look for. I'm only asking out of curiosity anyway to build up some knowledge. I don't have the kit to measure running voltages (yet, maybe I'll pick some up) but I can provide PCB photos for sure. The switch in discussion in SW1 at the top centre of the board and I'll link the model 

PCB: https://imgur.com/a/tAfvhyS

Switch: http://www.zippy.com/ecproductshowdetail.aspx?ps_rfnbr=287

Comment: I've deleted and moved my comment to be an answer, after you kindly provided photos of the PCB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary: Although I can't analyse the other sensors you mentioned using the photos, switch `SW1` is not carrying mains voltage.**

> Doesn't look like there's any voltage conversion circuitry

I bet there is. At the very least, the start/stop button won't usually have mains voltage on it, since the power for motors etc. doesn't pass through that, as the power to the motors continues even after the button is released. So my hypothesis is that the buttons are not carrying mains voltage and so their rating is sufficient.

A quick look at the new photos of the PCB confirms my hypothesis. They show a [capacitive dropper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_power_supply) type of power supply (that's the reason for the large yellow capacitor), what looks like a power diode for rectification (we can see `N4` in its part number e.g. perhaps `1N4007` or similar), a possible zener diode for regulation (we can see `39` in its part number - perhaps a 3.9 V zener?), and an electrolytic capacitor for smoothing.

**Note: This type of power supply means that the DC side of the device is not isolated from mains, and therefore should be treated as dangerous when energised.**

**If you are going to connect signals from inside this unit to other devices (you mentioned modifying it for automation), you must investigate techniques like opto-isolators.**

> The switch in discussion in SW1 at the top centre of the board

That is on the DC side of the power supply, and isn't switching mains voltages.

The circuitry also includes a PIC12F MCU controlling device `TR1` (a triac?) via a bipolar transistor `Q2` (we can just see markings for E and C) to switch the AC motor voltage (actually switching the `ACN` incoming mains wire, so probably the neutral) to terminal `M+`.

After more review of the photos, `SW1` is switching a logic-level signal to pin 3 on the PIC12F. That again confirms that it is switching a low-level signal and not mains voltage. Therefore its 3 A/125 VAC rating is not an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response and taking the time. Much appreciated :)

Comment: @Flowwwie - FYI I have updated my answer with more details. Especially important for you, if you intend to connect other devices to this one, is that its cheap capacitive dropper power supply means that the DC voltage used internally is referenced to mains, not to ground and not isolated (like typical USB "wall wart" power bricks) either.  For safety, you must not connect signals directly from the inside of this coffee grinder, to anywhere which can be touched by people. If you are not familiar with these issues, then as I mentioned, you need to investigate (suitable-rated) opto-isolators etc.

Comment: Thanks for the update and safety concerns. Was not planning on any external connections and I understand that it's double insulated and not earthed and the implications that brings. My current intention is to insert an opto-isolator + relay board in place of SW1, which will be switched by an RPI or equivalent.

Comment: @Flowwwie - Thanks for the reply. It was the point in the question about modifying it for automation, that made me think I should point out the consequences of the capacitive dropper power supply. Although you are already aware of that, hopefully my warnings will help future readers with similar devices :-) Good luck with the project!